# facebook comments plugin- unable to work on web server

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-comments

When I am using facebook comments plugin it is working on localhost but not working when I uploaded my files to web server.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

This two block of code generated from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
In the second block of code I changed the value of data-href="" and put my base url. is there any mistake I have done?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code. Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/8tJtZ/2/

There must be something wrong in code. Just double check your code.

Comment: hi Dead man plz check here: http://jsfiddle.net/8tJtZ/3/ its not working

Comment: It's working, let me show you this

Comment: check your question. I attached an screenshot

Comment: Mr. Dead please check: http://jsfiddle.net/8tJtZ/4/. when I'm changing data-href="http://myappdomain" then it's not working

Comment: If this is your domain : http://54.245.100.255/Andameter/ then it's definitely working as you saw i attached the screenshot.

Comment: I hv tried it but I dnt know why it is not working?

Comment: Can you provide me the url where you are testing this code?

Comment: yeah this is my site plz check it-http://54.245.100.255/Andameter/

Comment: I don't see any fb code when i viewed the source code here : http://54.245.100.255/Andameter/

Comment: Just click any category and you can find the facebook comment block. after that you can see.

Comment: so the facebook comment box is there : http://54.245.100.255/Andameter/anda/technology_pics/27

What's the problem then?

Comment: Try to post one comment on it .it is not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26233/discussion-between-debendra-samal-and-dead-man)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have an issue with comments here `base_url();` as it may expect your domain url but it might be blank in config.

Its hard to tell with the limited data (lack of errors) from your question.

I'm assuming you've used Chrome Inspector (or similar) to check the output for the HTML?